# how to create a list without duplicate and only add different data in a same primary key

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the sample data:

```
  public static List<DemoDataBindingByAnalysis> DataBindingByAnalysis
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<DemoDataBindingByAnalysis> {
                    new DemoDataBindingByAnalysis {
                        BCCode = "9105101",
                        BCName = "Allie Enterprise",                        
                        ItemCode = "1137806",
                        ItemDesc = "My Lunch Box Set (4)",                      
                        StandardPack = 8,
                        Amount = 46,
                        Date = DateTime.Parse("2018/03/05")
                    },
                     new DemoDataBindingByAnalysis {
                        BCCode = "9105101",
                        BCName = "Allie Enterprise",
                        ItemCode = "1137806",
                        ItemDesc = "My Lunch Box Set (4)",                   
                        StandardPack = 8,
                        Amount = 6,
                        Date = DateTime.Parse("2018/05/12")
                    },....
```

I've already tried using `Distinct` and `GroupBy` but the result is not what I expected. The result I want is like :

```
bccode1 | bcname | itemcode | item Desc | Stand Pack | Amount1 | Date1 |Amount2 | Date2
```

Comment: Do you not just want the latest object for that primary key?

Comment: I use [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) `DistinctBy` for these niggling issues.

Comment: The `Enumerable.Distinct` method accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>` so you can define a class that implements that interface and compares instances of your item type by the properties of interest and use that.

Comment: @JohanP can you show me? the only different between data is the amount and also the date. how can "distinctby" solves it?

Comment: @John actually i want the latest object for the primary just that it will only take the first data .

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you show me??

Comment: Instead of immediately asking others to show you, how about you do some investigation for yourself first?  There's no need for us to show you things that you can do for yourself and you don't know that you can't do it for yourself if you make no effort to try.  If people intended to write the code for you then they'd post an answer rather than a comment.  Providing keywords in comments is intended to give you some guidance as to what you should research.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the enumerable.disctinct only accepting data type int. fyi, the primary was a string.

Comment: @jmcilhinney its works. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this as per JohanP's comment;

```
MoreLinq DistinctBy:

var distinctData = DataBindingByAnalysis.DistinctBy(m => new { m.BCCode, m.BCName, ItemCode  }).ToList();
```

Add more fields as per your requirements.

MoreLinq is [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

else need to implement `IEqualityComparer` and then can use `Distinct`:

Sample code: (this is a reference, please modify as per your code)

```
class DemoDataEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DemoDataBindingByAnalysis>
{
 public bool Equals(DemoDataBindingByAnalysis x, DemoDataBindingByAnalysis y)
 {
    return x.BCCode.Equals(y.BCCCode) && y.BCName.Equals(y.BCName); //&& more fields here.
 }

 public int GetHashCode(DemoDataBindingByAnalysis obj)
 {
    return obj.BCCode.GetHashCode();
 }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include information about what provides DistinctBy, and I don't think that provides the full answer.

Comment: hi, ive try this code. and its not product a result that i expected

Comment: *produced . sorry typo